# group by using microsoft query

Tags: excel, ms-access, microsoft-query

I have a table like this in excel

```
ID | NAME | JOB     | PRICE
1  | alex | Java    | 100
1  | alex | C++     | 100
1  | alex | PHP     | 500
2  | road | Android | 400
2  | road | Ruby    | 400
3  | brit | Java    | 200
3  | brit | PHP     | 500
3  | brit | C       | 100
3  | brit | DotNet  | 300
```

I need output in following format

```
ID | NAME | JOB                   | PRICE
1  | alex | Java,C++,PHP          | 700
2  | road | Android,Ruby          | 800
3  | brit | Java, PHP, C, DotNet  | 1100
```

so i use Microsoft Query to generate this output using the following query

```
Select ID, NAME , GROUP_CONCAT(JOB) ,Sum(PRICE) from Table Group By ID;
```

but it keep to show me error  .. any suggestion

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` (and not specifying all non-aggregated columns in a `GROUP BY`) is supported by MySQL, but neither bei Access or Excel AFAIK.

Comment: There is no pure SQL using MS Access SQL to achieve that desired result assuming it is your data source. A combination of VBA may be needed.

Comment: i have the data in my file excel so i use Microsoft Query to allow me to use sql query in this data to generate table like this

Comment: Then, why are you tagging ms-access?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the closest you can get with SQL is the crosstab query which is available in the Jet/ACE SQL dialect. Jet/ACE is a set of Windows .dll files used for ODBC/OLEDB connections of MS Access databases and Excel spreadsheets. Do note Jet/ACE imposes a maximum limit of 255 columns.

Specifically, below calculates a running count of alphabetically ordered jobs (taking the max of repeat values) and then pivots from that source:

```sql
TRANSFORM Max(main.Job) As MaxOfJob
SELECT main.ID, main.[Name], Sum(main.PRICE) AS SumOfPrice
FROM (
   SELECT i.*, (SELECT Count(*) FROM [Sheet1$] sub
                WHERE sub.ID = i.ID AND sub.JOB <= i.JOB) As RunCount
   FROM [Sheet1$] i
) AS main
GROUP BY main.ID, main.[Name]
PIVOT main.RunCount;

-- ID   Name    SumOfPrice  1        2       3      4
-- 1    alex    700         C++      Java    PHP    
-- 2    road    800         Android  Ruby       
-- 3    brit    1100        C        DotNet  Java   PHP
```

Once you have a completed resultset, concatenate all the numbered column cells into the comma-separated *JOB* column with Excel's `CONCATENATE()` or loop through each column cell with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The way you want your table to look like includes a "Combined field", which is frowned upon in database design. You're initial design is correct, in the sense that each language takes up 1 entry in the table.